# How do I get the position of a sprite in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to programme a mouse that moves to the nearest pieces of cheese near it on the screen and eat it. However, in order to do so, I would need to find the positions/coordinates of other sprites. So how would I find the position of a sprite in Pygame? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation each sprite requires to have a `.rect` attribute.
See the documentation of [`pygame.sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html):

> The basic Sprite class can draw the Sprites it contains to a Surface. The `Group.draw()` method requires that each Sprite have a `Surface.image` attribute and a `Surface.rect`.

The `.rect` attribute has to be set by the application:

Again I'll refer to the documentation:

> When subclassing the Sprite, be sure to call the base initializer before adding the Sprite to Groups. For example:
>
> ```
> class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
>
>     # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
>     # and its x and y position
>     def __init__(self, color, width, height):
>        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
>        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
>
>        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
>        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
>        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
>        self.image.fill(color)
>
>        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
>        # Update the position of this object by setting the values of rect.x and rect.y
>        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
> ```

Of course the attributes can be directly set to the sprite object, too:

e.g.

```py
mySprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
mySprite.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
mySprite.rect = mySprite.image.get_rect()
```

After that the position can be get from the `.rect` attribute at any time. See [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

e.g.

```py
topLeftX, tolLeftY = mySprite.rect.topleft
```

```py
centerX, centerY = mySprite.rect.center
```