# How do i get the position of a text drawn with a function after I've used the same function for different texts?

Tags: python, pygame

```
def drawText(text, x, y, colour):

   font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 30)
   textSurface = font.render(text, True, colour)
   textRect = textSurface.get_rect()
   textRect.center = (x, y)
   screen.blit(textSurface, textRect)

drawText("YES", 120, 300, GREEN)
```

Later in the code, I want to get the position of the text "YES". How do get this value after I've used the same function to display other texts? I'm very new to python and pygame.

Comment: You could keep a collection of where all the texts have been.

Comment: You cannot determine the position of something drawn on the screen. You must save the position for later use. e.g. in a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object. See [How do I get the position of a sprite in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321669/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-a-sprite-in-pygame?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the coordinates into variables

```
def drawText(text, x, y, colour):

   font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 30)
   textSurface = font.render(text, True, colour)
   textRect = textSurface.get_rect()
   textRect.center = (x, y)
   screen.blit(textSurface, textRect)


textLocation = [120, 300]
drawText("YES", textLocation[0], textLocation[1] , GREEN)  


# Later on you need the coordinated of the text
# you can acces the location with textLocation[0] and textLocation[1]
print(f"Text is located at ({textLocation[0]}, {textLocation[1]})")
```

If later you start having a lot of texts, you might want to use a dictionary for example

```
textLocations = {
    "YES": {"x": 120, "y": 300},
    "NO": {"x": 200, "y": 100}
}
```

And access the location as

```
textLocations["YES"]["x"]
```

Take in account though, that keys are unique, so your key might need to be an id instead of just the text.